# No clue what's wrong with my code

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a program that takes two numbers, a subtotal and tax rate, and prints the sales tax and grand total. However, I've run into multiple problems writing it, so I've tried working backwards and dumbing it down to simply adding two numbers. Instead of adding the numbers, however, it is simply printing the two numbers side by side. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvNZox

HTML:

```
var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal");
var taxRate = document.getElementById("tax-rate");
var salesTax = document.getElementById("sales-tax");
var total = document.getElementById("total");

subtotal.addEventListener("input", calc);
taxRate.addEventListener("input", calc);

function calc()
{
    var sub = (subtotal.value) || 0;
    var tax = (taxRate.value) || 0;
    total.innerHTML = sub + tax;
}
```

JS:

```
var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal");
var taxRate = document.getElementById("tax-rate");
var salesTax = document.getElementById("sales-tax");
var total = document.getElementById("total");

subtotal.addEventListener("input", calc);
taxRate.addEventListener("input", calc);

function calc()
{
    var sub = (subtotal.value) || 0;
    var tax = (taxRate.value) || 0;
    total.innerHTML = sub + tax;
}
```

EDIT: My bad, forgot to add parseFloat before my value checks. Same problem still stands for when I go back to my original code:

```
var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal");
var taxRate = document.getElementById("tax-rate");
var salesTax = document.getElementById("sales-tax");
var total = document.getElementById("total");

subtotal.addEventListener("input", calc);
taxRate.addEventListener("input", calc);

function calc()
{
    var sub = parseFloat(subtotal.value) || 0;
    var tax = parseFloat(taxRate.value) || 0;
    salesTax.innerHTML = sub * (tax /100);
    total = sub + salesTax.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML and JS snippets are the same.

Comment: The title should give a short summary of the problem and not just a meaning less sentence which isn't helpful for others when searching for a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the logic for addition to below as previously it was considering it as a JavaScript string and instead of summing it was concatenating it. Explicitly converting it to an integer/double will prevent this. '||' handles non-numeric data in text field.

```js
var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal");
var taxRate = document.getElementById("tax-rate");
var salesTax = document.getElementById("sales-tax");
var total = document.getElementById("total");

subtotal.addEventListener("input", calc);
taxRate.addEventListener("input", calc);

function calc()
{
    var sub = parseFloat(subtotal.value) || 0;
    var tax = parseFloat(taxRate.value) || 0;
    salesTax.innerHTML = sub * (tax /100);
    total.innerHTML = sub + parseFloat(salesTax.innerHTML|| 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p> Subtotal: <input id = "subtotal"></p>
<p> Tax Rate: <input id = "tax-rate"></p>
Total: <p id = "total"></p>
Sales tax: <p id = "sales-tax"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay yeah I'm dumb, I forgot to add parseFloat lol. 

Now back to the primary problem: I still can't get the sales tax and the subtotal to add up. I now have this in my JS file:

    salesTax.innerHTML = sub * (tax / 100);
    total = sub + salesTax.innerHTML;

But this ain't working, it still just prints the numbers side by side. The tax rate is the only thing that is calculated correctly.

Comment: Could you please add this edit in your original question? I am not able to figure out the code! Thanks!

Comment: Done, the edit has been added.

Comment: @AustinKing  I edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for DAYS, now I can finally move on.

Comment: Could you accept my answer, if it helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're bumping into the fact that the `value`s are strings, and you can use `+` to concatenate strings as well as add up numbers.

Parse the number strings into actual Numbers first:

```
function calc()
{
    var sub = parseFloat(subtotal.value || 0);
    var tax = parseFloat(taxRate.value || 0);
    total.innerHTML = sub + tax;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the numerical value of the strings by using an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), for example.

This approach has the advantage, if a nonconvertable string is supplied, a [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) value is taken as [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value and together with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), you get zero as default value.

```
var sub = +subtotal.value || 0;
var tax = +taxRate.value || 0;
```

Comment: And why would he need to use an "unary plus"?

Comment: @Andreas It's just one of multiple ways to make the interpreter treat the values as numbers (as opposed to strings).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript considers the values as two strings and thus combines them.

Do something like this:

```js
var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal");
var taxRate = document.getElementById("tax-rate");
var total = document.getElementById("total");

subtotal.addEventListener("input", calc);
taxRate.addEventListener("input", calc);

function calc() {
  var sub = Number(subtotal.value) || 0;
  var tax = Number(taxRate.value) || 0;
  total.innerHTML = sub + tax;
}
```

```html
<p> Subtotal: <input id = "subtotal"></p>
<p> Tax Rate: <input id = "tax-rate"></p>
<p id = "total"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast string value to integer type. To do it you could use parseInt function:

```
total.innerHTML = parseInt(sub) + parseInt(tax);
```